# Embed music in Html - only the mute/unmute icon controller

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add in my home page mp3 music. From below code I have all the controlls (play, duration, volume etc.). I want to add only the mute/unmute icon with autoplay and infinite loop playing.

Html:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="/css/west.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this works for you :)

**HTML**:

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="/css/west.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div id="mute-toggle">Mute</div> <!-- mute / unmute toggle !-->
```

**jQuery (as you have it referenced)**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.autoplay = true;

    $("#mute-toggle").click(function(){ // on toggle click
        if($(this).hasClass("toggled")){ // if toggle has class "toggled"
            audio.muted = false; // unmute audio
        } else { // vice versa
            audio.muted = true;  
        }

        $(this).toggleClass("toggled"); // toggle class "toggled"
    });
});
```

**CSS**:

```
#mute-toggle{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url("url/to/unmuted/icon.jpg");
    cursor: pointer;
}
#mute-toggle.toggled{
    background: url("url/to/muted/icon.jpg") !important;
}
```

Let me know if you run into any problems!

Comment: I am using 1.9.1 jquery version and it shows me all the control panel again

Comment: @VasilisGreece what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I check it again. It says mute/unmute toggle but what I want is 1) the icon not letters, 2) It didn't start the music

Comment: @VasilisGreece give my new edit a shot. You will need to link your own mute / unmute icons.

Comment: Now it starts but it didn't stop and it didn't toggle. Remember I am using 1.9.1 version of jquery.

Comment: @VasilisGreece should still be working... But if not, link this within your head (and get rid of the old one) `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134247/discussion-between-vasilis-greece-and-grover).

Answer (score 1):

you'll need custom controls for this, it can't be done with the HTML audio element alone (which only allows all or no controls)

Check out jPlayer http://jplayer.org/ - this works quite well, offers a few pre-made "skins" and is configurable to a high extent.